# AngularJS: can't push $scope object onto end b/c data keeps updating

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Each time a user submits a form, the fields are in a `$scope.params` object. I want to track all submitted data on a `$scope.history` object. So I'm doing:

`$scope.history.push($scope.params)`

This isn't working, because when I output to console, each instance only shows the latest values submitted by the form. For example, if I submit a form three times, and each time I alter the "keywords", this is what it shows me:

```
{
    { keywords: 'Test 3' },
    { keywords: 'Test 3' },
    { keywords: 'Test 3' }
}
```

But this is what I was expecting:

```
{
    { keywords: 'Test 1' },
    { keywords: 'Test 2' },
    { keywords: 'Test 3' }
}
```

How do I get the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pushing a reference of `$scope.params` into the array so each element is pointing to the same object. You'll need to make a copy of it each time...

```
$scope.history.push(angular.copy($scope.params));
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. I knew the issue was with the reference, just didn't know how to get it to dump the data instead of use the reference. Still new to AngularJS. Much appreciated!